# How to set ST2 to prompt me every time whether I want to accept changes in the code made by some other program (git, for example)?

Tags: git, sublime-text-2

ST2 doesn't ask me if I want it to take new changes in my code. It just quietly reloads my source code. It happens for example when I do `git stash` or `git stash pop`. It just changes the code by force without informing me. I had some unpleasant situations with it, had to restore my work.

Is it possible to set ST2 so that it prompts me just every time when there are some changes in the code and it wants to reload it?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Sublime user settings (Preferences > Settings - User) and look for the following:

```
"autoReloadChanged":
```

Set `autoreloadChanged` to `false`. Sublime should default to this setting, so it may have been changed somewhere.

If that doesn't do it, look for this:

```
"ignoreChanged":
```

Set `ignoreChanged` to `true` to prompt for reloading changed files.

For more, see http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/file-type-preferences.